# Regex : How to remove empty lines only in the first comment block?

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of files all starting with a comment block such as this :

```
 /**
  * @author  AAA BBB
                             CCC DDDD

                       EEEE FFFF

  * @date    2008-08-14
  */
```

Sometimes there is only 1 author line :

```
 /**
  * @author  AAA BBB
  * @date    2008-08-14
  */
```

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that would remove the empty lines between @author and @date, but not in the rest of the file.

What I have currently :

```
(@author.*$)([\s\S]*)(^.*@date)
```

This is of course not enough but all my attempts to insert a (^$) in there led to wrong selections or infinite loops.

What is the correct regular expression ?

Comment: Regex in what?? Which environment/tool/language?

Comment: @Nupul is right, we can't help if you did not specify the tools you can use.

Comment: @Nupul On Linux, either with terminal tools or with JEdit.

Comment: Seriously, who voted down this question and why ? 
is it seriously because some information was missing ? then just ask like Nupul did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JEdit I finally got what I wanted by using the following regex :

```
(@author.*)([\s\S]*)(^$\n)( \* @date.*)
```

and the replacement string is

```
$1$2$4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which environment/tool/language you are going use but something on these lines should do the trick - in Vi/sed (not tested)

```
\/\*.*\([\*\t\s\S\n\r]*\)\(@author.*\).*\([\*\t\s\S\n\r]*\).*\(@date.*).*\*/\
```

This is what it means:

Look for a string that starts with /* can be followed by any character(s). It may contain any whitespace till it encounters '@author' again, characters/whitespaces and then '@date' ending with other characters and closing with */

You basically want to do "substring" regexing (if it's even a word) - look for a large pattern and extract sub patterns in it (demarcated by \( and \) - escaping round brackets.

You can then refer to the expression(s) positionally like \1 \2 and so on. Basically substring \(...\)everything you want to keep and just replace in the end using \1 \2 etc., This should work fine as long as this pattern doesn't repeat elsewhere :)

Hope this helps. It may not be "the perfect" regex but you get the idea of how to structure it and extract substrings...

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to find the correct expression i was looking for !

Comment: You "should" select an answer you know :) even if it's your own :) Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

If you have `vim` installed and the `@author` and `@date` labels occur only once per file, you can do:

```
vim -e '/@author/,/@date/v:.:d' -e 'x' FILE
```

If you have several files, you should use:

```
vim -e 'buffdo!/@author/,/@date/v:.:d' -e 'xa' FILES
```

Vim will open the file(s), then search for the blockrange, then search for empty lines (a single space is not empty line!), then deletes them and write the file(s) and exits.

HTH

Comment: +1 for this great tip. I've always wanted to know how to do it properly :)